# Multiplas linhas em um ShowMessage no Delphi

Tags: delphi, csv, concatenação-de-string

Preciso disparar uma mensagem de erro caso o usuário tente inserir códigos inválidos em uma tabela temporária no *grid*. Os códigos são provenientes de um `.txt`. Os códigos disparados no monitor estão ok porém a mensagem é repetida n vezes conforme existam n códigos incorretos. Gostaria que fosse disparada uma única mensagem com a lista de códigos incorretos. Como fazer isso? Obrigada.

```
// procedure para leitura do texto 
var
    myFile : TextFile;
begin
    AssignFile(myFile, arquivoTxt);

    Reset(myFile);

    while not Eof(myFile) do
    begin
        ReadLn(myFile, text);
        InsereTexto;
    end;
    CloseFile(myFile);
end;

// procedure para inserir dados do txt no banco 
begin
    if not qrSELCSPCliente.Locate('CSC_CAP_NroCartao', StrToInt(text), []) then
    begin
        {INSERE DADOS NO BANCO do txt} 
    else
    begin
        MsgAviso('Número já cadastrado!' + text);
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simples!
Adicione o caractere `#13` (enter) ao fim de cada linha.
Mas antes, crie uma variável temporária para ir acumulando as mensagens, e exiba-as de uma só vez ao final do processo

```
//procedure1 para leitura do texto 
var
    myFile : TextFile;
    mensagens:String;
begin
    mensagens:='Números já cadastrado!';//Inicializa a variável
    ...
    if not qrSELCSPCliente.Locate('CSC_CAP_NroCartao', StrToInt(text), []) then
    begin
    {INSERE DADOS NO BANCO do txt}
    end 
    else 
        mensagens:=mensagens+#13+ text);
    //veja que aqui ja terminou todo while
    if mensagens <>'' then
        MsgAviso(mensagens);
end;
```

Comment: Ricardo, muito obrigada! Solução elegante e funcional. Declarei "mensagens" como variável global e após `CloseFile(myFile);` da procedure para leitura de texto eu zerei a variável "mensagens".

Answer (score 2):

Complementando a resposta do @Ricardo, você tem várias maneiras de incluir uma nova linha em uma string. Veja abaixo vários exemplos comentados:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    Msg: string;
begin
    Msg := '';

    Msg := Msg + 'Linha 01'#13;                      // (1)  Comum de se encontrar em códigos Delphi
    Msg := Msg + 'Linha 02'#10;                      // (2)  Padrão Posix (Linux, OSX, Android, iOS, etc.)
    Msg := Msg + 'Linha 03'#13#10;                   // (3)  Padrão Windows
    Msg := Msg + 'Linha 04' + sLineBreak;            // (4)  Multiplataforma
    Msg := Msg + 'Linha 05' + chr(13);               // (5)  Mesmo que (1)
    Msg := Msg + 'Linha 06' + chr(10);               // (6)  Mesmo que (2)
    Msg := Msg + 'Linha 07' + chr(13) + chr(10);     // (7)  Mesmo que (3)
    Msg := Msg + 'Linha 08' + ^M;                    // (8)  Mesmo que (1)
    Msg := Msg + 'Linha 09' + ^J;                    // (9)  Mesmo que (2)
    Msg := Msg + 'Linha 10' + ^M^J;                  // (10) Mesmo que (3)
    Msg := Msg + AdjustLineBreaks('Linha 11'#10);    // (11) Mesmo que (1), mas ajusta para a plataforma usada
    Msg := Msg + AdjustLineBreaks('Linha 12'#13);    // (12) Mesmo que (2), mas ajusta para a plataforma usada
    Msg := Msg + AdjustLineBreaks('Linha 13'#13#10); // (13) Mesmo que (3), mas ajusta para a plataforma usada
    Msg := Msg + 'Linha 14';

    ShowMessage(Msg);
end;
```

Eu costumo usar `sLineBreak` pois é multiplataforma e pode evitar futuros problemas caso reutilize um código em várias plataformas. Mas se não for o seu caso, utilize o que achar melhor.

Answer (score 1):

Para completar as demais respostas com um processo pouco mais simples!

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('Linha 01'+#13+
              'Linha 02'+#13+
              'Linha 03'+#13+
              'Linha 04'+#13+
              'Linha 05'+#13+
              'Linha 06'+#13+
              'Linha 07'+#13+
              'Linha 08'+#13+
              'Linha 09'+#13+
              'Linha 10'+#13+
              'Linha 11'+#13+
              'Linha 12'+#13+
              'Linha 13'+#13+
              'Linha 14)';
end;
```

Se você usar `+#13#13+` ele salta duas Linhas.